# Big company unorganised, no training plan and no work

Tags: new-job, job-change, helping

I'm currently in a situation where the job I was hired for has no full days worth of work for me to complete. I feel like I am expendable in my role.

The following has arisen since I have started.

- the team leader that hired me, has left and the team knew about this prior to me starting for about 10 weeks
- I have been there for 5 weeks starting next week, they still have no clients for me to chase and take ownership off
- there is no training plan in place for what I should be achieving as the acting team leader is busy doing her own role.
- I have been proactive asking people and team leaders for work. I have spoken to the manager and he eventually asked other people in the team for work and they almost had argument for giving me work as the team members don't want me to contact their clients.

I'm in a position where the work that eventually be out into my pipeline will become boring and my motivation asking for work is just waning. I'm at the point of I don't care if I get any work, I just want to leave, but not until I have secured another opportunity.

Would it be bad practice to ask the internal recruiter that was handling mr appointment for other roles?

Comment: user26642 and user26617, are you the same user?  If so, you can [merge them](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 13):

> Will it be bad to start applying for new jobs in the same company or
>   should i just start looking for other things outside of the business.

Not only would it look bad to apply for a different job in the same company, in many companies it wouldn't be permitted. Many companies won't let you consider a transfer until you have been in your current position for at least 6 month or so.

I think you are being a bit impatient.

It sounds as if the situation changed unexpectedly with your manager having left. When things are in flux like this, it often takes some time for it to settle down, and for tasks to start getting assigned smoothly. As you indicated "it's only been 3 weeks".

Meanwhile, this is your chance to be proactive, and pursue work in your current role that would have value to you, and wold help your team.

Approach whoever is supervising your work now. Explain that you have free time and are looking for important work that needs to be done. Offer to help others. Ask if there are books or documents you can read, or online learning materials that you can exercise to help you be better prepared for your role.

Ask your peers if they need help and how you can pitch in.

> Or should i sit here and wait for things to fall in my lap.

Sitting there waiting doesn't sound like a good way to show your new company how valuable you are. Find ways that you can do better than that and make yourself useful.

Comment: I'm not sitting there, I have been proactive, I've been speaking to the acting manager and my team members for things to do. I even asked if I could build reports for the team and I have been shot down and been told no I as they own discussing things to look into for their KPI's.  Also I've been left out today from a coaching session so I can look after the phone. What am I suppose to do? I'm not being impatient, its just that there isn't any work available for me to do.

Comment: If there's really no work, there MUST be education you could be doing -- on the company's procedures, on the tools you're using, on the market, etc. Ask your manager. Ask the manager who hired you and then changed assignments. Ask your co-workers what you should be reading up on, or whether there are online courses you could be taking. But, seriously, don't panic and don't take it personally.  It may take a few weeks for them to get organized enough to start using you productively. Especially in your situation, where management changed before you were assigned a role.